# importing multiline JSON file in python

Tags: python, json, import

I am trying to import a JSON file in python that has many objects like the following:

```
{"ID": 1989,  "Attrib1": "74574d4c6",    "Attrib2": null,    "Attrib3": "41324" }
{"ID": 1990,  "Attrib1": "1652857c6",    "Attrib2": asd123,    "Attrib3": "424" }
```

The file has line break for each object therefore, the `json.load(file)` is failing on the first line break.

I tried to iterate through them with:

```
with open(myFileLocation,'r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        Data = json.loads(row)
return Data
```

but I couldn't add each line to a dictionary object as it doesn't have append (or any other method that am aware of).

How can I return all the objects in the JSON file as a dictionary?

Comment: You can create an empty dictionary with `my_dict = {}` and add new key-value pairs to it with `my_dict[new_key] = new_value`. First though, you'll need to decide which field of your JSON object you want as the key.

Answer (score 0):

json.loads (and json.load) does not decode multiple json objects.

```
>>>json.loads('{}')
{}
>>>json.loads('{}{}')
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most 
recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-0285b42a3a05> in <module>()
    ----> 1 json.loads('{}{}')

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    352             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    353             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook 
is None and not kw):
    --> 354         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    355     if cls is None:
    356         cls = JSONDecoder

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    340         end = _w(s, end).end()
    341         if end != len(s):
    --> 342             raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
    343         return obj
    344 

JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
```

To dump multiple dictionaries, you could wrap them in a list by dumping the list.

```
>>> dict1 = {}
>>> dict2 = {}
>>> json.dumps([dict1, dict2])
'[{}, {}]'
>>> json.loads(json.dumps([dict1, dict2]))
[{}, {}]
```

Also Use append as follows

```
list = []
    for line in open('data.json'), 'r'):
    list.append(json.loads(line)
```

Comment: I am able to add the file content as a list but, I need to analyze the JSON data and I can't do that on a list as far as I know it should be a dictionary.

Comment: d = dict(itertools.zip_longest(l[::2], l[1::2], fillvalue=''))

This can convert the list to a dictionary.